# Excel IF statement not matching exact data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm using an Excel IF statement to try to output specific values if the input values roughly match what is expected. Example: If the number 89.48282949 is input, I want the formula to recognize the input as 89 and then output 7. Is there any way to round the input so the formula works without having to match the expected input exactly? Thanks for the help.

```
=IF(C2>=1,"0",IF(C2=0.85,"56",IF(C2=0.86,"52",IF(C2=0.87,"48",IF(C2=0.88,"44",IF(C2=0.89,"40",IF(C2=0.9,"36",IF(C2=0.92,"28",IF(C2=0.93,"24",IF(C2=95,"16",IF(C2=96,"12",IF(C2=97,"8",IF(C2<0.85,"0")))))))))))))
```

Expected: input of .8495849294 rounds to .85, which outputs 56. (as an example)

Comment: You can create a table where you put the bottom of each range and the expected value next to it, then do a non-exact lookup where it takes the expected value until it reaches the next value. From the formula you gave, either you excluded decimals or the logic is noncontinuous. Ie: it's unclear from 89.48... where 7 comes from; from .8495 to 56, therefore it seems a table and lookups may be more suited for this.

Comment: use `ROUND(C2,2)` where ever you have `C2` and remove the `""` around the numbers so numbers are returned and not text that looks like numbers

Comment: Similar to @MarkS. comment, but without creating a table: Instead of `IF(C2=0.89,"40")`, use `IF(AND(C2>=0.89,C2<0.9),"40")`